# Guava and SQL: cast int to Ints

Tags: java, guava

I'm pulling data from MSSQL server and the rest of the application relies heavily on guava. Is there a way to convert int from SQL to Ints (guava)?  I've tried

```
Primitives.wrap(Ints.class).cast(resultSet.getInt(3)))
```

and get an "java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Integer to com.google.common.primitives.Ints" error.

Comment: After reading the guesswork about what your goal might be, I wonder: if what you want is an `Integer`, just use `getObject` instead of `getInt`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Ints`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/index.html) is a static utility class, it doesn't have instances.  It's there to provide common methods to manipulate primitive `int`s.  If you need to wrap it in a class, the natural one is `java.lang.Integer`.

[`Primitives.wrap()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/index.html) is sort of a meta-utility.  It tells you what *class* implements the wrapper for a given *class*.  If you provide the primitive `int.class`, it will return `Integer.class`.  Again, it manipulates classes, it doesn't wrap a primitive value.

If you want to wrap an `int`, all you need is:

```
int fooToWrap = 42;
Integer fooWrapped = Integer.valueOf(fooToWrap);
```

What are you trying to accomplish?

Given your comment, I think what you want is:

```
Integer.valueOf(resultSet.getInt(3))
```

Comment: I was using ArrayListMultiMap<Timestamp,Integer> and eventually a ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> with a lot of manipulation in between. The cast errors arise from the first phase, i.e. going from the database to the ArrayListMultiMap. Thanks

Comment: @blue: OK, but your first sentence is not relevant, if I understand correctly.  Can you provide more detail about how the "first phase" looks?  I still don't know why you think you want an instance of `Ints`.

Comment: I'd use the `Integer.valueOf(int)` static factory method instead of the `new Integer(int)` constructor, which lets you benefit from the Integer cache. I believe that's what auto-boxing does under the hood when converting ints to Integers.

Comment: @eneveu: Thanks, and agreed.  Made that change.

Comment: You can of course also use autoboxing to just do "Integer foo = resultSet.getInt(3)". I also once wrote a utility for extracting an `Integer` from a `ResultSet` that returns `null` if the value in the database was `null` (by calling `getInt` and then `wasNull`) if that's what you want. Otherwise you get `0` when the database has `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you can only do a cast like that, if int extends ints.
Have you tried making it into an Integer object, and not just an int datatype?